# What is the syntax for converting XML to HTML using PSCX Convert-XML?

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt, pscx

There is a commandlet in PSCX called Convert-XML that uses XSL to convert XML into HTML. I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax to get it to work.

I know I need to feed it paths for the XML input, the XSLT style sheet, and the HTML output.

How would one convert **C:\input.xml** into **C:\output.html** using **C:\style.xslt**?

Comment: What have you tried already? Looking at the help for the cmdlet, looks like `Convert-Xml -Path input.xml -XsltPath style.xslt -OutputPath output.html` should work.

Comment: When I try that, I get an error: "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OutputPath'

Comment: If I remove -OutputPath output.html it works, but just echos the HTML in powershell as opposed to writing it to a file.

Comment: `help convert-xml` shows an `-OutputPath` parameter for me. Which version of PSCX are you using?

Comment: 2.1, I think...

Comment: If you are running the command in powershell, could you just user Powershell's redirection operator? `Convert-Xml -Path input.xml -XsltPath style.xslt > output.html`

Comment: Well, if the version you have doesn't support `-OutputPath`, what happens if you `Convert-Xml > file.html` or `Convert-Xml | Out-File file.html` (with the other arguments on `Convert-Xml` of course)

Comment: Alternatively can you update `pscx` to the latest version? I just updated mine and it is `3.3.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went back and forth in the question comments a bit, but I'm certain this is the correct answer:

```
Convert-Xml -Path input.xml -XsltPath style.xslt -OutputPath output.html
```

However, as you noted, you are on 2.1 of PSCX, which is fairly out of date and doesn't seem to support the `-OutputFile` parameter. You can try using the `Out-File` cmdlet or redirection operator to output the rendered HTML document to a file like so:

```
# Using Out-File
Convert-Xml -Path input.xml -XsltPath style.xslt | Out-File output.html

# Using redirection operator (>)
Convert-Xml -Path input.xml -XsltPath style.xslt > output.html
```

Note that both `Out-File` and `>` adds a byte-order mark (BOM) to your file. If that is undesirable, you can do this to write the file without the BOM:

```
# Save the converted HTML to a variable
$htmlDoc = Convert-Xml -Path input.xml -XsltPath style.xslt

# Create a new UTF8 encoding with no BOM
$UTF8EncodingNoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding( $False )

# Write to file using the no-BOM encoding
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText( 'output.html', $htmlDoc, $UTF8EncodingNoBom )
```